# start detached infinite process with python on windows and pipe the output into a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, subprocess

I am trying to start a process with python that runs infinitely and pipe it's output into a file. The new created process should keep running after the python executable exits. 
I am able to start a process and keep it running when python exits with this code:

```
subprocess.Popen(command_list, creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS | subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | subprocess.CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB)
```

Now I am trying to pipe the output of the started process into a file, but i can't get it working together with detaching the process.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this ?

please note that i am trying to achieve this on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just redirecting *stderr* and *stdout* to two files:

```
from subprocess import Popen

from subprocess import DEVNULL
from subprocess import DETACHED_PROCESS
from subprocess import CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP
from subprocess import CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB

command_list = ...

creationflags = DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB

with open("stdout.txt", mode="wb") as out, open("stderr.txt", mode="wb") as err:
    Popen(command_list, creationflags=creationflags, stdin=DEVNULL, stdout=out, stderr=err)
```

Make sure to check `stderr.txt` and `stdout.txt`, since the output from your process could be redirected to either.

Comment: `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` is almost meaningless when combined with `DETACHED_PROCESS` (i.e. don't inherit or allocate a console). The group it refers to is a console process group, since the console is the only system component that uses it, and only as a filter for `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`.

Comment: I strongly suggest to override all standard handles as valid file handles when using `DETACHED_PROCESS`, since some console apps will fail if a standard handle is invalid. Set `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`.

Comment: by the way for any one that looks on this in the future there is a mix with stderr and stdout file naming and where they are piped. @RoadRunner

Comment: @DavidLichterov I'm testing on Windows and most of the time the actual output gets piped to stderr.txt. Must be a windows issue, because on linux it gets piped to stdout.txt.

Comment: @RoadRunner I think it depended on what process are you running. I am running qemu and it's output is going correctly to stdout. Any way This could make people become confused.

Comment: @DavidLichterov Yeah that's true. I've added a comment in the answer to make sure both files are checked.